# Import [Module] could not be resolved (PylancereportMissingImports), with module in the same folder/directory

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-import

The first few lines of the code of `evaluation.py`:

```py
import os
import torch
from torch.nn import functional as F
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import numpy as np
from dataset import CLSDataset # warning is reported here
from tqdm import tqdm
```

The structure of the folder:

```
./
|-dataset.py
|-dictionary.py
|-evaluation.py
|-model.py
|-models/
  |-[some files]
|-__pycache__
|-train.py
```

Notice that `dataset.py` is in the same folder as that of `evaluation.py` and https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/blob/main/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#unresolved-import-warnings says that *The language server treats the workspace root (i.e. folder you have opened) as the main root of user module imports.* But it still throws an warning of "Import dataset could not be resolved".

I tried to add the

```
{
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": ["./"]
}
```

on the settings.json of both local and remote files, but it does not help.

Comment: Can the code run successfully? Please use the form of tree diagram to describe the structural relationship of related files and folders.

Comment: The code can run successfully, the structure of files and folders updated.

Comment: Which python language service are you using? Please try to use the language service provided by "Jedi" or "Microsoft".

Answer (score 5):

In VSCode, go to the main window and do the following:

1. Do Ctrl+Shift+P (for Windows) and Command+Shift+P (for Mac)
2. Scroll and go to **Python Select Interpreter**
3. Now select whichever python version is installed in your system.
4. You're good to go!

Do upvote if it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Dataset is a relative import.

Add an __init__.py file your directory (a file with no content). Then try:

```
from .dataset import CLSDataset
```

That being said, Python imports are a tricky business. It looks like we’re only getting a glimpse of one part of workspace setup.

(I am surprised that your code runs as-is.)

Consider scaffolding your project with [cookiecutter](https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). Also try out the vs code [python project tutorials](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/tutorial-flask). You don’t have to remake your entire project but these will give you a starting point for understanding where your current project goes awry.

Answer (score -1):

I recently had the same error, just try restarting the IDE. You probably installed it thought the code was already open. Or you haven't installed the module at all.


Edit:

I'm sorry I understood it wrong, please send the code.


Edit2:

You need to add the `.py` at the end of the import if it is a `.py` file

Comment: restarting the IDE does not help, and the module is just a file in the same folder, so it just cannot be installed.